# Telerik MVC Grid in Razor view, GridCommand not populating

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik mvc grid in a Razor view. I am using custom server binding. My issue is that on paging and sorting the GridCommand object properties "Page", "PageSize" & "SortDescriptors" are not getting the correct value. The funny thing is that the exact same code works for an aspx view. Since this is a new view, I have started using "Razor".
My view is -

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid((IEnumerable<Mitek.MobileImaging.AdminSite.Models.ImagingTransactionModel>)ViewData["DeficientGridView"])
   .Name("DeficientImagesGrid")
   .DataBinding(databinding => databinding.Server()
   .Select("ViewDeficientImages", "SuperAdmin", new { orgId = ViewData["OrgId"], beginDate = ViewData["BeginDate"], endDate = ViewData["EndDate"], searchString = ViewData["SearchString"] }))
   .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(o => o.TranId))
   .EnableCustomBinding(true) 
   .BindTo((IEnumerable<Mitek.MobileImaging.AdminSite.Models.ImagingTransactionModel>)ViewData["DeficientGridView"])
   .Columns(
        columns => 
        { 
            columns.Template(
                                @<text>
                                   <a href="@Url.Action("DeficientImageDetails", "SuperAdmin", new { id = item.TranId }) ">
                                   <img alt="Deficient Image Details" src= "@Url.Content("~/Content/ImagesUI/detail_icon.gif")"  style="border:0px" /></a>   
                                 </text>
                            ).Title("Actions").Width(75);
            columns.Bound(o => o.TranId).Hidden(true);
            columns.Bound(o => o.user_email).Title("User Email").Width(250);
            columns.Bound(o => o.xml_config_name).Title("Job File").Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.datetime_created).Title("Date Created").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.short_note).Title("Note").Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.iqa_code).Title("IQA Code").Width(200);
        }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = " font-family:arial; font-size: .9em;  " })
   .Sortable()
   .Pageable(paging => paging.Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom)
                            .Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric)
                            .Total((int)ViewData["DeficientImagesCount"])
                            .PageSize(25))    
)
```

The controller looks like

```
[GridAction(GridName = "DeficientGridView")]
public ActionResult ViewDeficientImages(DeficientImagesViewModel model, GridCommand command, string button)
{
    //Some Code......;            
    GridCommand myCommand = new GridCommand() { PageSize = 25 };
}
```

The command object never has any values for command.Page, command.SortDescriptors at the time of paging or sorting. Please note that the exact same code works in a asps page.
Please help.

Thanks,
SDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if it has to do with `[GridAction(GridName = "DeficientGridView"]` attribute and your grid name being different`.Name("DeficientImagesGrid")` ?

Comment: Thanks!...dont know how I did not see, something so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true, GridName = "DeficientImagesGrid")] to this. I have the same problem today and i found this is working. If you don't specify the GridName then you will not get GridCommand.

- gridCommand is NOT populated when the query string parameters are QueueGrid-size=2&QueueGrid-page=3
- gridCommand is populated when the query string parameters are size=2&page=3